# 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 1: character maps to <undefined> при попытке чтения CSV файла

Tags: python

Столкнулся с проблемой чтения CSV файла. Сам код выглядит так:

```
import csv
def csv_reader(file_obj):
    reader = csv.reader(file_obj)
    for row in reader:
        print(' '.join(row))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    csv_patch = 'output.csv'
    with open(csv_patch, 'r') as f_obj:
        csv_reader(f_obj)
```

Comment: а csv файл как выглядит в position 1?

Comment: не очень знаю... :(